# Can I exclude lines starting with #?

Tags: python, python-requests

Line 4 counts number of lines from response. Trying to exclude lines that start with # from the count.Possible?

```
def fetch_block_count(session: requests.Session, url: str, timeout: int):
    try:
        with session.get(url, timeout=10) as response:
            dooct = {url: len(resp.text.splitlines())}
            return dooct
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        return 'booger'
```

Pasted code incorrectly and fixed it.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more your question? It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Line 4 counts number of lines from response. Trying to exclude lines that start with # from the count.

Comment: do you mean particularly this `len(response.text.splitlines())`?

Comment: "Line 4" - yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can trivially use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for what you are trying to do:

Use `len([l for l in response.text.splitlines() if len(l)<1 or l[0] != '#'])`

Comment: do i have to do a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You could exclude the lines that start with `"#"` by applying a filter to a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as follows:

```py
dooct = {
    url: len(
        [
            line for line in response.text.splitlines()
            if line and not line.startswith("#")
        ]
    )
}
```

Notice that `line and not line.startswith("#")` will be `True` if and only if `line` is not `""` and the line does not start with `"#"`.